# Select row from group which satisfies condition A. If not, give me a row that satisfies condition B

Tags: sql, oracle

I bring forth an interesting problem that has been bothering me for the past few days. Let's say you have the following data structure:

```
Col1 |  Col2    | Col3 | Col4
100  | "Val1"   | 0    | 100
100  | "Val2"   | 1    | null
100  | "Val 3"  | 0    | null
101  |  "Val4"  | 0    | null
101  |  "Val5"  | 1    | null
102  |  "Val6"  | 0    | null
```

I need that one row where `Col4!=null`. If all rows' `Col4` is `null` then return me a row where `Col3=1`, but if both `Col4` is `null` and `Col3=0`, then return me any one row.

So the result set for the above data will look like,

```
Col1  |  Col2    |  Col3  | Col4
100   |  "Val1"  |   0    |  100
101   |  "Val5"  |   1    | null
102   |  "Val6"  |   0    | null
```

***I know this could be done using analytics function, order them by `Col1`, `Col4` and `Col3` and use an analytic function to get the first row in each group but we are using our inhouse ORM that doesn't support analytic function.***

Please let me know if this can be done using simple SQL (JOIN, Case, etc).

---

Edit:

There will only be one row per group where `Col4` has non-null value and one row per group where `col3` is `1`. Also, a single row in the group can satisfy both conditions of having `Col4` not `null` and `Col3=1`.

Comment: It looks like you did not mention that you want Col1 to be the partitioning key. Otherwise the above set would return only 1 row (the first one) since your logic should exit at the first row where Col4 is not null

Comment: Is that possible to have multiple non-null col4 values for each ID? If so, return all of them or any row?

Comment: Please see my edit.

Answer (score 2):

How about this? Every `CONDx` CTE solves one condition.

- `COND1` returns rows whose `COL4` is not null
- `COND2` returns rows whose `COL1` doesn't exist in `COND1` result set and has NULLs for `COL4` (in that case, count of distinct values = 0) and `COL3` = 1
- `COND3` is everything that's left

The final result is union of all those.

```
SQL> with test (col1, col2, col3, col4) as
  2    (select 100, 'val1', 0, 100  from dual union all
  3     select 100, 'val2', 1, null from dual union all
  4     select 100, 'val3', 0, null from dual union all
  5     select 101, 'val4', 0, null from dual union all
  6     select 101, 'val5', 1, null from dual union all
  7     select 102, 'val6', 0, null from dual
  8    ),
  9  cond1 as
 10    (select col1, col2, col3, col4
 11     From test
 12     where col4 is not null
 13    ),
 14  cond2 as
 15    (select col1, col2, col3, col4
 16     from test t
 17     where t.col1 not in (select col1 from cond1)
 18       and col1 in (select col1
 19                    from test
 20                    group by col1
 21                    having count(distinct col4) = 0
 22                   )
 23       and col3 = 1
 24    ),
 25  cond3 as
 26    (select col1, col2, col3, col4
 27       from test t
 28       where t.col1 not in (select col1 from cond1
 29                            union all
 30                            select col1 from cond2
 31                           )
 32    )
 33  select col1, col2, col3, col4 from cond1
 34  union all
 35  select col1, col2, col3, col4 from cond2
 36  union all
 37  select col1, col2, col3, col4 from cond3
 38  order by col1;

      COL1 COL2       COL3       COL4
---------- ---- ---------- ----------
       100 val1          0        100
       101 val5          1
       102 val6          0

SQL>
```

Comment: If you add one row like: (100, 'val7',0,101), it will return two rows for group 100. So it does not work like OP mentioned.

Comment: That can't happen@Gen Wan, as the OP said "There will be only one row per group where Col4 has non-null value" - in your example, that would make **2 rows** with COL4 being not null.

Comment: My bad, I did not notice that.

Comment: No problem at all :)